# How to replace a specific slice in a string?

Tags: python, string

Suppose I have this string:
`Long long ago, there lived a king.`

Now, I want to replace the second "long" with something else, I already got the starting and the ending position in the string for the second "long".

How do I replace that specific "long" with "ABCD" given that I already have the slice for it?

Comment: Are you trying to replace all double words like (so-so, long-long, very-very, etc.), or just *long*? If it is for all, is `ABCD` the fixed replacement or it should be dynamic based on the word or length?? It'd be easier for the community to help if you're specific with your problem rather than asking incomplete or open-ended questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string slicing

> str1=str1[ : startIndex]+"ABCD"+str1[endIndex+1 : ]

where startIndex=5 and endIndex=8 in the example you gave